# syntax for merging two tables without column

Tags: powerquery

I am merging two tables where I have 3 conditions to match. But one of them is not the column but only text as "320" for the column "Hesap Grubu".

```
 #"Merged Queries" = Table.NestedJoin(#"Removed Duplicates", 
                     {"FirmaID", "Hesap No", {320}},
                     #"Mizan Özet", {
                      "FirmaID", "Hesap No", "Hesap Grubu"}, 
                     "Mizan Özet", JoinKind.RightAnti),
```

I tried 320 and also {320} but it didnt work. Is there any proper syntax for that ?

I also tried as VAR but it is looking for the column named "320" ‍♂️

```
HesapGrubu = "320",
Table.NestedJoin(#"Removed Duplicates", {"FirmaID", "Hesap No", HesapGrubu }
```

I could add one custom column to the table as 320 but i wont prefer if there is a proper syntax to solve faster...

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the table name with Table.AddColumn (tablename, "new column", each 320) before using it

Comment: thank you but I've known this option already but it shouldnt be necessary to add a column to merge tables... i think no such option developed yet in powerquery...

Comment: Yes, powerquery does not have an option yet to merge on a column that does not exist